Matplotlib Radar chart ticks rotation issue
I'm attempting to create a radar chart using matplotlib. My goal is to position each label so that it points towards the center of the circle from different angles, similar to what's shown Fig.1 Figure 1. However, I'm currently encountering this result instead (Fig. 2): Figure 2.
Please advise me on how to adjust my code to achieve the appropriate rotation of labels? Thanks in advance!
Here is my code:
import math
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('./results/zh_en_annotation_eval.csv', sep=',',
                 index_col=0, header='infer', encoding='utf-8')

labels = df.columns.values.tolist()
N = len(labels)
values = df.loc['r'].values.tolist()

angles = [n / float(N) * 2 * math.pi for n in range(N)] + [0]


def plot_radar_chart(ax, angles, values, label, color, alpha=0.2):
    values += values[:1]
    ax.plot(angles, values, linewidth=1, linestyle='solid', label=label, color=color)
    ax.fill(angles, values, alpha=alpha, color=color)


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16, 12), subplot_kw={'projection': 'polar'})

ax.set_theta_offset(math.pi / 2)
ax.set_theta_direction(-1)
ax.set_xticks(angles[:-1])

for i, angle in enumerate(angles[:-1]):
    angle_deg = np.degrees(angle)
    rotation = angle_deg + 90
    label_position = 1.1
    ax.text(angle, label_position, labels[i], transform=ax.transData,
            ha='center', va='center', rotation=rotation, color='grey', size=10)

maximum = math.ceil(df.loc['r'].max())
minimum = 0.0
ticks = np.linspace(minimum, maximum, 3)
plt.yticks(ticks, labels=[str(tick) for tick in ticks], color='grey', size=7)
plt.ylim(minimum, maximum)

plot_radar_chart(ax, angles, values, label='r', color='red')

ax.set_xticklabels([])
plt.title(f"En-Zh Pearson Correlation", size=11, y=1.1)

plt.legend(loc='upper right', bbox_to_anchor=(1.1, 1.1))
plt.savefig('./results/zh_en_annotation_rader_plot.png')


GPTs could not help with that.

This question is similar to: How to rotate tick labels in polar matplotlib plot?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Oh! Got it. Thanks a lot!
